# How to save Google API marker objects for futures use

Tags: google-maps

I am using the drawing tool api of Google Maps API to create markers. Since markers created that way need to get saved manually, I was wondering what would be the most efficient way. I am really a beginner in web language so I was seeking some tips. Few ways I thought of were using $.ajax to sent the data to php and save it in sql. There was an article about using xml parsing but I couldn't really understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to save the position of the marker you can:

```
var pos = marker.getPosition();

$.post('/path/to/server/', {lat:pos.lat(), lng:pos.lng()}, function(response) {
    //response
});
```

On the php side you would just be looking for the `$_POST['lat'] and $_POST['lng']` values to save